# Need to create procedure to validate SSN in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

So I have in one of the tables SSN that needs to be validated and list of all where SSN is missing or not valid. I have code below to validate that, with creating temp table where is  the list of High Group data that is used to generate the next set of SSNs, taken from SSA's website. So I have inserted into temp table and now I need to use function below in order to validate if SSN is valid or not. What is best way to do that? Create function using code below and call function from Stored Procedure or there is other way?

```
DECLARE @ssn VARCHAR(15)
SET @ssn = ' '

SELECT 
        @ssn SSN,
        CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(@SSN, '-', '')) <> 1 OR Sequence = 0 OR HighGroup = 0 THEN 'Invalid SSN' 
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN Groupcode % 2 = 1 THEN --odd groupcode 
                CASE WHEN GroupCode <10 THEN 
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 AND HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                    ELSE 'Invalid SSN' 
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 0 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                    WHEN HighGroup % 2 = 1 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    END
                END
            ELSE --even groupcode
                CASE WHEN GroupCode >= 10 THEN
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup %2 =1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <=9 THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    WHEN HighGroup %2 = 0 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    END
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN HighGroup %2 =1 THEN
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup <=9 THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                    WHEN HighGroup %2 = 0 THEN 
                        CASE WHEN HighGroup >=10 THEN 'Valid SSN' 
                        WHEN HighGroup < 10 THEN 
                            CASE WHEN HighGroup <= GroupCode THEN 'Valid SSN' ELSE 'Invalid SSN' END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END [ValidSSN]
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    LEFT(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(@SSN, '-', '')))) + REPLACE(@SSN, '-', ''), 3) Area,
    SUBSTRING(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(LTRIM(REPLACE(@SSN, '-', '')))) + REPLACE(@SSN, '-', ''), 4, 2) HighGroup,
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@SSN, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@SSN, '-', ''), 4) Sequence,
    REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(REPLACE(@SSN, '-', ''))) + REPLACE(@SSN, '-', '') SSN
) v
LEFT JOIN ##SSN_RangeList sr
    ON v.Area = CAST(sr.AreaCode AS VARCHAR(3))
```

Comment: What rules are you using for the validation?  This should be a check constraint.

Comment: So those are the rules:  SSN is broken into three parts xxx-xx-xxxx, the first three represent the AreaCode (geographical location), the next two represent the GroupCode and the last four represent the sequence. SSA website publishes the list of High Group data that is used to generate the next set of SSNs, and the list can be downloaded from the following link http://www.ssa.gov/employer/ssns/HGDec0110.txt. For a particular AreaCode, the GroupCode is issued in a "Odd", "Even", "Even", "Odd" pattern as described below:

Comment: 1. Odd numbered GroupCodes "01", "03", "05", "07", "09" are issued first for any areacode
2. Even numbered GroupCodes between "10" and "98" are issued next
3. Even numbered GroupCodes "02", "04", "06", "08" are issued next
4. Finally odd numbered GroupCodes between "11" and "99" are issued.

Comment: And If you click on the link it will give you list of area numbers and the group, I have created temp table and inserted those numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I have understood your question correctly, you have some working code that validates the SSN and you want to know the best way of implementing it? If that is the case then:

1. If you will want to use the logic to return a single value (valid/invalid) in multiple different scenarios e.g. SELECT statements, stored procedures, etc. then create it as a function as that is the most flexible.
2. If you only need to use the logic in one place and it is part of a wider piece of functionality that is run regularly (e.g. a process to identify all invalid SSNs and then correct them) then I would incorporate it into a Stored Procedure

Comment: I have multiple db's where SSN is stored and would be used through to validate all, it is part of data migration. Once Data Migration is completed it will be used for validation if SSN is valid and if not report will be created and sent up to business to correct invalid SSN's.